# Can the URL be read by third parties when browsing via HTTPS?

Tags: privacy, https

We all know that HTTPS encrypts the connection between the computer and the server so that it cannot be viewed by a third party. However, can the ISP or a third party see the exact link of the page the user accessed?

For example, I visit

```
https://www.website.com/data/abc.html
```

Will the ISP know that I accessed */data/abc.html or just know that I visited the IP of www.website.com?

If they know, then why does Wikipedia and Google have HTTPS when someone can just read the internet logs and find out the exact content the user viewed?

Comment: Hint: If you don't register your account, visit this place from various IPs, and don't keep your cookie, participation in Super User will be a little… fragmented, which means you can't even accept answers on your own posts, or add comments. I highly suggest you register an account here.

Answer (score 49):

From left to right:

The **schema** `https:` is, obviously, interpreted by the browser.

The **domain name** `www.website.com` is resolved to an IP address using DNS. Your ISP **will see** the DNS request for this domain, and the response.

The **path** `/data/abc.html` is sent in the HTTP request. If you use HTTPS, it **will be encrypted** along with the rest of the HTTP request and response.

The **query string** `?this=that`, if present in the URL, is sent in the HTTP request – together with the path. So it's also encrypted.

The **fragment** `#there`, if present, is not sent anywhere – it's interpreted by the browser (sometimes by JavaScript on the returned page).

Comment: You forgot that modern browsers which support SNI announce the hostname in plain text even for HTTPS requests.

Comment: @Kurian: Which matters little, since the hostname is already "announced" by DNS.

Comment: @Kurian: the IP address *could* be acquired by other means, but in practice it rarely is. And looking at a single protocol in isolation without considering how it's *actually* used is prone to miss the important parts.

Comment: I don't know whether Tor uses the same exit node for resolving names and establishing the actual HTTPS connection, or different ones. If it uses separate nodes, then it's still the only place where SNI would matter.

Answer (score 13):

The ISP will only know you visited the IP address associated with `www.website.com` (and maybe the URL if you are using their DNS and they are specifically looking for the traffic – if the DNS query does not go through that they won't see that).

(Bear with me a bit here – I do get to the answer.)

The way the HTTP protocol works is by connecting to a port (usually port 80) and then the web browser communicates what page it wants to the server – A simple request to look up `http://www.sitename.com/url/of/site.html` would have the following lines:

```
GET /url/of/site.html HTTP/1.1
host: www.sitename.com
```

HTTPS does exactly the same thing except on port 443 – *and* it wraps the entire TCP session (i.e., everything you see in the quoted bit above plus the response) into an SSL encrypted session – so the ISP does not see any of the traffic (but they may be able to infer something based on the size of the site, and the DNS lookup to resolve `www.sitename.com` to an IP address in the first instance).

Of course, if there are "web bugs" embedded in the page, this can give "partners" of the information distributors hints about what you are viewing and who you are – likewise, if your chain of trust is broken, an ISP can perform a man-in-the-middle attack.  The reason why you can have private end-to-end encryption, in theory, is because of CA certificates distributed with your browser.  If an ISP or government can either add a CA certificate or compromise a CA – and both have happened in the past – you lose your security.  I believe that The Great Firewall of China effectively does Man-In-The-Middle attacks to read HTTPS data, but it's been a while since I was there.

You can test this easily enough yourself by getting a piece of software which will sniff the traffic entering and leaving your computer.  I believe a free piece of software called Wireshark will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is comment or answer worthy, but I'd like to share one addendum.

The answers here show what *should* happen. The question is *can* the url be read.The answer to that is yes, though it is relatively unlikely.

An attacker (third-party) can absolutely intercept your https traffic and read all of your requests under specific cases. To learn more, I'd invited you to read [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) as well as [SSLStrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/). I can go into this more if necessary for understanding.

You should not expect your ISP to be doing this both because it is a waste of their bandwidth but also because they have more to lose if you were to find out and sue. However the more precise answer to your question Can this be done? is yes, though it is unlikely anyone will care enough to see what you're googling or wiki-ing.